# Spring Integration Dynamic Flows threads issue

Tags: java, java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am creating dynamic integration flows as based on the data from the database.

The directories which we need to poll with the file name pattern are in the databse

e.g.

```
Instance, directory , filename 
ABC     , c:/input1  , test.txt
DEF     , d:/input2 ,  fresh.xlsx
```

I have some 200-300 entries so what I am doing is creating Integration flow for each record as it will have different processor etc

**for each record**

```
 IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder =
                        IntegrationFlows
                                .from(new CustomFileReadingSource(input), consumer);

     flowBuilder.transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer());

      flowBuilder.handle(o -> {

    //                System.out.println(o.getPayload());
                });
context.registration(flowBuilder.get()).register();
```

Once all of them are registered but when I look at the VisualVM or the log I only see 8-10 threads instead of 100 or 200.

from the log

```
2018-11-13 16:00:41.399 [task-scheduler-3] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:41.587 [task-scheduler-10] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32)
2018-11-13 16:00:41.807 [task-scheduler-4] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:42.071 [task-scheduler-5] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:42.323 [task-scheduler-7] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:42.569 [task-scheduler-6] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:42.878 [task-scheduler-8] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:43.197 [task-scheduler-9] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:43.588 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:43.951 [task-scheduler-2] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:44.305 [task-scheduler-3] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:44.598 [task-scheduler-10] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32)
2018-11-13 16:00:45.031 [task-scheduler-4] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:45.414 [task-scheduler-5] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32) 
2018-11-13 16:00:45.974 [task-scheduler-7] INFO  c.b.m.p.f.b.LoggerSourceAdvisor.afterReceive(32)
```

As you can see its only few threads polling the thread

Could someone help why it does not create threads or any better way to achieve parallel pollers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Because all `Polling Ednpoints` are based on the predefined global `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with the `10` as pool size by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler

On the other hand it is really pointless to try to have 100 thread meanwhile your CPU is maximum 16 cores. Making more threads may even cause slowing down of your application.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. Is there anyway smarter/efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do? Can I have one poller and once I get the file then I can invoke a particular flow ?

Comment: I would suggest you do not create so many dynamic flows, but have just one with some `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` implementation to iterate over those directories after each poll. You can find some ideas in the `RotatingServerAdvice`. After polling you can do some routing based on the message content. I don't see reason to abuse Dynamic flows in your case.

Comment: Artem Bilan. Thanks a lot. I felt the same that was sort of abusing the dynamic flows. Do you have example on RotatingServerAdvice ?

Comment: The `RotatingServerAdvice` is not going to work for you because it is for remote protocols, (S)FTP, S3 etc. In your case it is plain local file system, so, you need just borrow a rotating algorithm from that class. The sample is here in there test-case though: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ftp/inbound/RotatingServersTests.java

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are suggesting. Just one last question. Lets say I still the build the flows to process the file as each file will be totally difference process steps. Once I get the file then how do I invoke a particular flow. OR can I setup the channels dynamically then based on the file name/pattern I can send to that channel. Sorry for many questions but your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. you can do that too: based on the message content you can do routing to the channels created at runtime by that dynamic flows mechanism. The point is: try to keep dynamic flows as small and light as possible. Faster start up, cleaner shutdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry to annoy you sir but do you have example on " routing to the channels created at runtime by that dynamic flows mechanism." . :)

Comment: Huh? You just use a regular Router which is able to rely on the channel name you return from the routing function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-routers

Comment: Man, you are just amazing. Sorry for being noob here but trying to learn the ropes :) Thanks a lot ! seriously

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler).

The default scheduler has only 10 threads. Normally, scheduled tasks are short running, in which case, this is usually enough; if not, either increase the thread count or add a task executor, so the scheduler hands off the work to another thread.

Comment: Thanks Gary. You guys are really gurus on Spring integration :)